# XAML -- Managing events between pages

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have a C#/XAML application built on MVVM model. I have controls setup under a folder in the application. I want to turn on/off the visibility of a small block (say a UI Element), which I setup as a sub grid, on page 1 by checkin/unchecking a checkbox in page 2. Both pages are under control. 
I created a new event for both check and uncheck and gave a name to all the elements mentioned here. I cant seem to access the Grid from page2.xaml.cs in intellisence to bind the event to its visibility. Can you please explain if I missed something!!

Comment: Without adding some code you will most likely get no answer. [mcve]

Comment: You say you are using MVVM - so I don't think you should really be "accessing the Grid from page2.xaml" as this is pretty counter to the MVVM pattern, which uses data binding to a viewModel to manage things like that. We really need to see some code and what you've attempted to help!

Comment: Page 1: Has check boxes, that are displayed on the main page using a <local /> tag
Page 2: has the grids to be visualized using those check boxes, again displayed on main page using local tag
Both these pages are not really binding to any VM but the main page is!

Comment: Really need to see some code. We can't help with what's wrong without seeing what's wrong. It's impossible to do with a few lines of description.